# whats the difference between long long int and long double?

Tags: c++

this is the question in spoj "atoms in the lab".http://www.spoj.com/problems/ATOMS/

the below code is giving me **tle** in spoj

In the question it's clearly mentioned that n,m,k are integers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex>
#define ll long long int
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ll p;
    scanf("%lld",&p);
    while(p--)
    {
        ll n,m,k;
        ll ans=0;
        scanf("%lld%lld%lld",&n,&k,&m);
        while(n<=m)
        {
            ans++;
            n*=k;
        }
        if(ans>0)printf("%lld\n",ans-1);
        else
            printf("0\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

whereas the code below is giving **Ac** in spoj

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex>
#define ll long long int
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ll p;
    scanf("%lld",&p);
    while(p--)
    {
        long double n,m,k;
        ll ans=0;
        scanf("%Lf%Lf%Lf",&n,&k,&m);
        while(n<=m)
        {
            ans++;
            n*=k;
        }
        if(ans>0)printf("%lld\n",ans-1);
        else
            printf("0\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

the only difference between the 2 codes is long long int and long double.
can anyone clarify me why this is happening ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`long long int` is for large integers ( cannot contain decimals ).

`long double` is for large doubles ( can contain decimals )

And , the problem with your first code might be

```
ll p;
scanf("%d",&p);
```

`p` is a `long long int`, but you are using `%d` for it when you should be using `%lld`. But you fixed that in your second code, so it does not have that error.

Comment: i didnt understand ur explanation , can u explain it relavent to what i asked?

Comment: @rap , I've added a possible reason for your code failing

Comment: even its giving tle for scanf("%lld",&p);